# Why this Python code is much slower on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, python-3.x, fibonacci

I've been trying this Python iterative code to get the Fibonacci sequence on Windows and Linux. The problem is that this code takes much longer to execute on Windows and I don't know why. Is it due to the memory management of Windows? Both OS use Python 3.

```
def fib(n):
     old = 0
     new = 1
     temp = 0

    for i in range(1,n):
        temp = new
        new = new + old
        old = temp

    return new

def main():
    a = 10000
    for i in range(1,51):
        start_time = time.time()
        fib(a)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print("%.10f" % elapsed_time)
        a = a+10000
```

The time is measured in seconds.

Time graph:

[image: Time graph]

Thank you.

UPDATE: cProfile on both OS

[Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwFfx.png)

[Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J86rV.png)

The "percall" time seems to be huge on Windows compared to Linux.

Comment: You should use an actual profiler on both OS and see what is the bottleneck. FWIW, I realize this is not what this question is about, but you can use a formula to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number in O(1).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the information with two screenshots using cProfile. The difference between both OS is huge, but I don't know what's happening there. I guess is something related to the memory management and the execution plan.